# How can i get values out when i've got a hash of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, hash

I am getting the following code in my params (send from a simple form in haml with a simple_field_for block. All the data I needed is in here but I'm having trouble getting it out the way I wanted.

**my params:**

```
"report_templates"=>{"1"=>{"start_year"=>"2015", "start_period"=>"", "use_concept_data"=>"0", "name"=>"Financieel jaaroverzicht", "id"=>"1"},    "3"=>{"start_year"=>"2015", "start_period"=>"", "use_concept_data"=>"0", "name"=>"Klanten", "id"=>"3"}}
```

I have report_templates with settings for each report template. now in the controller I want to use these setting to render a .pdf report for each template.

**what I need is:**

```
"1"=>{"start_year"=>"2015", "start_period"=>"", "use_concept_data"=>"0", "name"=>"Financieel jaaroverzicht", "id"=>"1"}
```

I now I can access the settings by doing

```
params[:report_template]["1"]
```

and getting this back

```
{"start_year"=>"2015", "start_period"=>"", "use_concept_data"=>"0", "name"=>"Financieel jaaroverzicht", "id"=>"1"}
```

But I want to do it dynamic in my controller. because the id of the report_template can be any number.

**my controller:**

```
report_settings = params[:report_templates]
report_settings.each do |rs|
 rs[:id]
```

But I am not getting the id from each template..

I hope someone can help me solving my problem.

Comment: You're asking for `rs[:id]` but in the code above the id is a string, so shouldn't you be instead asking for `rs["id"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you were close. But little more work need to be done.

```
report_settings = params[:report_templates]
report_settings.each do |report_id, report_value|
  # now you have access to the key(report_id) 
  # and value(report_value) both
end
```

If you don't need *key*, but only values, then :

```
report_settings = params[:report_templates]
report_settings.each do |_, report_value|
  # now you have access the value(report_value)
end
```

Read [`Hash#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) method for detail documentation.

Comment: @SteffenWitvliet Can you tell me what next you want.. I am seeing only the data..

Comment: I need all the keys and values for each report_template.
so I can later use those values to render a pdf report for each template.

so let's say I want to generate a pdf for report template with id 1. [:report_template]["1"] I need the value 2015 from the key start_year which is needed to generate the content for the template

Comment: I've tried your first option which seems right.

`report_settings = params[:report_templates]
report_settings.each do |report_id, report_value|
  report_value[:start_year]
end`

I hoped it will give me back the values from the key start_year?

Comment: @SteffenWitvliet Yes.. it should.

Comment: eventually I need all settings like: 
- start_year
- start_period
- id
- name
- use_concept_data

for each report_template. I have to have those values and will store those for later use.

`def report_settings
    report_settings = params[:report_templates]
    report_settings.each do |key, value|

      options = {
        report_id: value[:id],
        report_name: value[:name],
        start_year: value[:start_year],
        start_period: value[:start_period],
        use_concept_data: value[:use_concept_data]

      }
    end

    exit
  end`

Comment: @SteffenWitvliet Well.. What is your problem.. what is not working.,.

Comment: Well I get the values, but only for the first report template. not for all. if I do value[:start_year] I get 2015. which is good. but my other report template has start_year 2014. and I don't get those values

Comment: @SteffenWitvliet Ahh!.. replace `each` with `map!`.. and you are done!! :D

Comment: map! raises an error: undefined method `map!' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00000014511be8>

a normal map works but is no different then each and returns just values from first report_template